# Linux kernel patch and development source tree

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

We are using linux3.12 and its led driver has a bug which got fixed in later version of Linux.  We see that driver change in Linux 3.15 see [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/diff/drivers/leds/led-core.c?v=3.15;diffvar=v;diffval=3.14)

Now my question is how can I find a patch which induced this change ?

Another question is how can I get access to development kernel source tree e.g. kernel-3.14.18 tree ?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I find a patch which induced this change

Use cgit, go [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git) and click on *tree*. Navigate to the file you're looking for and then click *log*. You can then see the changes to the file.

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/drivers/leds/led-core.c

To download the Linux kernel sources, go to kernel.org and choose your version.

The unstable development tree is here:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/

Comment: i couldn't see kernel version's source tree which is not stable.

Answer (score 2):

### getting the kernel source

Clone the stable kernel tree:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

Change into it:

```
cd linux-stable
```

Checkout a tag where the bug is fixed:

```
git checkout v3.15
```

You know the file you're after `drivers/leds/led-core.c` and where the bug is fixed (3.15) and broken (3.12) so there are a few ways you can proceed from here.

### blame

You could use `git blame drivers/leds/led-core.c` but i find this view messy.

I prefer `tig`, a curses-based interface to git, so just:

```
tig blame drivers/leds/led-core.c
```

and view each line of the file and those commits interactively. You can go up and down with the arrow keys, and go into a commit with **Enter**. Exit with **q**.

You can see the patch you linked to in LXR on Lines 42-46:

```
2014-02-04 00:11 Stefan Sørensen 8d82fef         /* never on - just set to off */
2014-02-04 00:11 Stefan Sørensen 8d82fef         if (!delay_on) {
2014-02-04 00:11 Stefan Sørensen 8d82fef                 __led_set_brightness(led_cdev, LED_OFF);
2012-03-23 15:02 Bryan Wu        a403d93                 return;
2014-02-04 00:11 Stefan Sørensen 8d82fef         }
```

So you're looking for `8d82fef`. Press **Enter** over any of those lines and you'll open the patch.

This is much more useful for bigger files with lots of recent patches.

### log

You need a date range, so looking in `git log` of the "good" and "bad" tags, the 3.15 and 3.12 merges were:

```
commit 1860e379875dfe7271c649058aeddffe5afd9d0d
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Jun 8 11:19:54 2014 -0700

    Linux 3.15
```

and

```
commit 5e01dc7b26d9f24f39abace5da98ccbd6a5ceb52
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sun Nov 3 15:41:51 2013 -0800

    Linux 3.12
```

So anything between Nov 2 2013 and Jun 8 2014 is your patch.

Look in the log of the file in question:

```
git log drivers/leds/led-core.c
```

The only patch which matches this date range is the latest one:

```
commit 8d82fef8bbee588d071372eb02439d2053b4bfe4
Author: Stefan Sørensen <stefan.sorensen@spectralink.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 4 00:11:42 2014 -0800

    leds: Turn off led if blinking is disabled
```

### the patch

Now you've used either of those methods to find the commit which fixes your problem, get the patch of the commit, compared to its ancestor, with:

```
git diff 8d82fef8^ 8d82fef8 drivers/leds/led-core.c
```

You can pipe this to a file if you want:

```
git diff 8d82fef8^ 8d82fef8 drivers/leds/led-core.c > led-blinking-fix.patch
```

Now you have a patch to apply to your in-house kernel tree.